# Spring batch: Input resource does not exist class path resource

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch

I am currently developing a Spring Batch which converts an Excel (.xsls) file to CSV in first step and then reads the CSV, processes it and stores its data in database.
The first step works well. The batch stops at the second step throwing this warning: `Input resource does not exist class path resource [C:/work/referentielAgenceCE.csv]`. Here after my code:

spring-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd">

    <!-- import config Spring générale -->
    <import resource="classpath*:spring/***-batch-spring.xml" />

    <bean id="pathFichier" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="${batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathCSV}" />
    </bean>

    <batch:job id="simpleFileImportJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
        <batch:step id="convertStep" next="processingStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="convert"/>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step id="processingStep">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="agenceCEReader" processor="agenceCEProcessor" writer="agenceCEWriter" 
                    commit-interval="5" />              
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>

    <bean id="convert"
        class="com.***.referentielAgenceCE.convertTasklet.convertXLSXtoCVS" />

    <!-- Reader -->
    <bean id="agenceCEReader" scope="step"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">     
        <property name="strict" value="false" />
        <property name="resource" ref="pathFichier" />
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean
                        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                        <property name="names"
                            value="Date Création,Date Dernière modif.,Date Début Validité,Date Fin Validité,Caisse,Identifiant Agence,Libellé Agence,Type Agence,Libellé Type Agence,Téléphone,Fax,2EME Ligne Adresse,3EME Ligne Adresse,4EME Ligne Adresse,5EME Ligne Adresse,6EME Ligne Adresse,Pays,Ville,Identifiant Niv. 1,Type Niv. 1,Libellé Niv. 1,Identifiant Niv. 2,Type Niv. 2,Libellé Niv. 2,Identifiant Niv. 3,Type Niv. 3,Libellé Niv. 3,Identifiant Niv. 4,Type Niv. 4,Libellé Niv. 4,Identifiant Niv. 5,Type Niv. 5,Libellé Niv. 5,Identifiant Niv. 6,Type Niv. 6,Libellé Niv. 6,Identifiant Niv. 7,Type Niv. 7,Libellé Niv. 7,Identifiant Niv. 8,Type Niv. 8,Libellé Niv. 8,Identifiant Niv. 9,Type Niv. 9,Libellé Niv. 9,Identifiant Niv. 10,Type Niv. 10,Libellé Niv. 10,Identifiant Niv. 11,Type Niv. 11,Libellé Niv. 11,Identifiant Niv. 12,Type Niv. 12,Libellé Niv. 12,Identifiant Niv. 13,Type Niv. 13,Libellé Niv. 13,Identifiant Niv. 14,Type Niv. 14,Libellé Niv. 14,Jours/Heures Ouverture,Code Etat" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean
                        class="com.***.referentielAgenceCE.mapping.AgenceCEFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processor -->
    <bean id="agenceCEProcessor" 
        class="com.***.referentielAgenceCE.processor.AgenceCEItemProcessor"/>

    <!-- Writer -->
    <bean id="agenceCEWriter"
        class="com.***.referentielAgenceCE.writer.AgenceCEItemWriter" />
</beans>
```

Step 1 - convertXLSXtoCVS.java:

```
public class convertXLSXtoCVS implements Tasklet, InitializingBean{


    @Value("${batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathXLSX}")
    private String inputFile;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("convertXLSXtoCVS.execute1");
        // For storing data into CSV files                
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();                
        try {
            File outputFile = new File(getOutputFile(inputFile));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputFile.getPath());

            BufferedWriter  fos = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            // Get the workbook object for XLSX file
            XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(inputFile));

            // Get first sheet from the workbook
            XSSFSheet sheet = wBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row;
            Cell cell;

            // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                // For each row, iterate through each columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    cell = cellIterator.next();
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:                                                
                            data.append(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + ",");                                                
                            break;                                        
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:                                                
                            data.append(cell.getNumericCellValue() + ",");                                                
                            break;                                        
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:                                                
                            data.append(cell.getStringCellValue() + ",");                                                
                            break;                                        
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:                                                
                            data.append("" + ",");                                                
                            break;
                        default:                                                
                            data.append(cell + ",");
                    }
                }
            }
            fos.write(data.toString());
            fos.close();
        }catch (Exception ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        Assert.notNull(inputFile, "inputFile must be set");

    }

    public String getOutputFile(String inputFile){
        String[] parts = inputFile.split("\\.");
        return parts[0]+"."+parts[1].replace("xlsx", "csv");
    }

}
```

I mention the file paths in a properties file as follow:

```
batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathXLSX=C\:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.xlsx
batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathCSV=C\:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.csv
```

When I delete  from the spring-config.xml in the reader definintion, I get the following error :

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:137)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy44.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:93)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL [file://work//referentielAgenceCE.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:250)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:134)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution. I should just add 'file:' to the output cvs file path. so it should be like this :

```
batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathCSV=file\:C\:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.csv instead of C\:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL [file://work//referentielAgenceCE.csv]
```

And more precisely :

```
file://work//referentielAgenceCE.csv
```

I think you need to replace :

```
batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathXLSX=C\:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.xlsx
batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathCSV=C\:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.csv
```

by

```
batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathXLSX=C:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.xlsx
batch.referentielAgenceCE.inputFilePathCSV=C:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.csv
```

Comment: @NabilSalah Try with `file:` before the driver letter (`file:C:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.xlsx`)

Comment: Worst this time it return the following error : file:C:\\work\\referentielAgenceCE.xlsx does not exist

Comment: @NabilSalah Can you try with slashes instead of backslashes? `C:/work/referentielAgenceCE.xlsx`

Comment: still the first warning :  WARN  | Input resource does not exist class path resource [C:/work/referentielAgenceCE.csv]. I think it is not due to the file path.

Comment: After debbuging I noticed that the file is created in the same time the second step starts (the step where we read the CSV). I do not know if there is a way to make a break between the two steps ?

Comment: @NabilSalah Theorically, if you add a StepExecutionListener in your steps, you'll see that the `afterStep` of your first step is called after the file is created and before the `beforeStep` method of your second step which reads this file. There souldn't be any need to add a delay or a break between the steps. Have you tried putting a file in the folder independantly of its creation in the first step?

Comment: I added an intermediary step between the first step and the second. In this intermediary step i put a Thread.sleep(100000) : You are right, it does not resolve the problem(so no need for a break or a delay). I tried putting a file in the folder independantly of its creation in the first step : the file is well read processed and data are written in Database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93665/discussion-between-nabil-salah-and-thrax).