# Spring Batch Partitioning inject stepExecutionContext parameter in itemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, partition

I am trying to learn Spring Batch with Partitioner.

The issue is that I need to set the filenames dynamically from the Partitioner implementation. And I am trying to get it in the `itemReader`. But it gives filename **null**.

My Spring Batch configuration:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Transaction> itemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[filename]}") String filename) 
    throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    FlatFileItemReader<Transaction> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<Transaction>();
    DelimitedLineTokenizer tokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    String[] tokens = { "username", "userid", "transactiondate", "amount" };
    tokenizer.setNames(tokens);
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource(
        "input/"+filename));
    DefaultLineMapper<Transaction> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Transaction>();
    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(tokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(new RecordFieldSetMapper());
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setLineMapper(lineMapper);
    return reader;
}
@Bean(name = "partitioningJob")  
public Job partitioningJob() throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {  
    return jobs.get("partitioningJob").listener(jobListener()).start(partitionStep()).build();  
}  

@Bean 
public Step partitionStep() throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {  
    return steps.get("partitionStep").partitioner(step2()).partitioner("step2", partitioner()).gridSize(2).taskExecutor(taskExecutor).build();  
}  

@Bean 
public Step step2() throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {  
    return steps.get("step2").<Transaction, Transaction> chunk(1).reader(itemReader(null)).processor(itemProcessor()).writer(itemWriter(marshaller(),null)).build();  
}  

@Bean 
public TransactionPartitioner partitioner() {  
    TransactionPartitioner partitioner = new TransactionPartitioner();  
    return partitioner;  
}                           

@Bean 
public JobListener jobListener() {  
   return new JobListener();  
} 

 @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(2);
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
```

And my `TransactionPartitioner` class is:

```
public class TransactionPartitioner implements Partitioner {  

public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int range) {  
    Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();  
    for (int i = 1; i <= range; i++) {  
        ExecutionContext exContext = new ExecutionContext();  
        exContext.put("filename", "input"+i+".csv");
        exContext.put("name", "Thread" + i);  
        result.put("partition" + i, exContext);  
    }       
    return result;  
}  
}
```

Is this not the right way to do it? Please suggest.

This is the stack trace:

```
  18:23:39.060 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob - Upgrading JobExecution status: StepExecution: id=1, version=2, name=partitionStep, status=FAILED, exitStatus=FAILED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.baeldung.spring_batch_intro.App.main(App.java:24)
; org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource [input/null]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144)
    ... 9 more
```

As per @Sabir's suggestion, I checked my data. The step context table looks like this:

```
  | STEP_EXECUTION_ID | SHORT_CONTEXT | SERIALIZED_CONTEXT |
|                 1 | {"map":[{"entry":[{"string":"SimpleStepExecutionSplitter.GRID_SIZE","long":2},{"string":["batch.stepType","org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep"]}]}]} | NULL    
|                 2 | {"map":[{"entry":[{"string":["filename","input2.csv"]},{"string":["name","Thread2"]}]}]}                                                                                            | NULL               |
|                 3 | {"map":[{"entry":[{"string":["filename","input1.csv"]},{"string":["name","Thread1"]}]}]}
```

**Here is the full code for it:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bziay9b2ceLbUXdTRnZoSjRfR2s/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went through your code and tried to run it.

Currently it is not binding the file name at scope level.

You have two configuration files:

1. SpringConfig - containing Spring related config beans
2. SpringBatchConfig - containing Spring batch related beans

The first one contains the annotation `@EnableBatchProcessing` and `@Configuration`.

But the `itemReader` is defined in another config file which do not contain any of the annotations.

You should have `@Configuration` on the other file too.

OR

You can add both the annotations to `SpringBatchConfig` config file and can skip them in `Spring`

Without this, these configurations are not read properly and the `itemReader` is not considered as Step Scoped (i.e. the annotation `@StepScope` does not work) and does not bind the values at step level, and hence you are getting the `NULL` values.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thanks a lot. Have been banging my head on a silly mistake since days.

Answer (score 1):

Its not application code's responsibility to call `partition` method like you are doing in below ,

```
@Bean 
public TransactionPartitioner partitioner() {  
    TransactionPartitioner partitioner = new TransactionPartitioner();  
    partitioner.partition(10);  
    return partitioner;  
}
```

Framework will call `partition` method for you. You simply need to return `Partitioner` without calling `partition(10)` method explicitly.

Having said that , you need to set partitioner `gridSize` in partitioner step as shown below,

```
@Bean 
public Step partitionStep() throws UnexpectedInputException, MalformedURLException, ParseException {  
    return steps.get("partitionStep").partitioner(step2()).partitioner("step2", partitioner()).gridSize(10).taskExecutor(taskExecutor).build();  
}
```

Above points might be root cause for your issue. Rest of the things seem OK with your code.

Comment: Thanks @Sabir, I tried it, but I am still facing the issue, I have updated the question with the stack trace.

Comment: That stacktrace indicates that your set up  is working now. That is a reader specific issue about not finding file. You can google that trace to find a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33363214/spring-batch-input-resource-does-not-exist-class-path-resource) and [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/89363-input-resource-must-exist-reader-is-in-strict-mode-class-path-resource-data-foo). This error was there from beginning but your execution wasn't reaching to this point before.

Comment: If value of `String filename` is empty or null in reader , try using syntax `exContext.putString(...,...)`  instead of `exContext.put(...,...)`. Also establish that String value is null or empty by printing only that value or debugging reader.I mean everything looks OK now, now rely on debugging to figure out your issues. Put break points in partitioner & reader plus examine meta data to see if values getting saved there. meta tables with suffix `_CONTEXT` will have your partitioner data , look at those tables.

Comment: Once `partition(int gridSize)` returns , data gets saved to meta context tables then injection of values to steps etc starts so verify that partitinioner is completing successfully and values getting saved in meta tables.

Comment: Yes, I verified that the filename I am getting is NULL, also I checked the database table BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT and found that the map that was added to ExecutionContext is stored in the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT.SHORT_CONTEXT but the values for BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT.SEARIALIZED_CONTEXT for each of them is NULL. Is this relevant?

Comment: I think, what matters is `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT.SHORT_CONTEXT` . If values are there, reader should get those values. Something else seems wrong with your code or set up.

Comment: Okay, can you suggest me some working example of Spring batch partitioner with java config?

Comment: I have many working projects of my own with partitioning & java config but I am not able to figure out mistake in your code. Please upload full code along with processor and writer, I will try to set up on my machine to see if something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Sabir, I've updated the question with the link to the full code. It uses mysql db "test"

Comment: Were you able to find the issue @Sabir? Thanks for helping out.

Comment: Sorry, did't got time and then was on vacation. Glad that your issue is resolved by other answer.